# Write Query in CDBCriteria in Yii with Where and Group By clause

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have this query, I want to do this query using CDbCriteria. Model is `Clog`

```
SELECT c.id, c.answer, c.number
FROM `Clog`as c
WHERE c.company_id =20
AND date(c.answer) = '2016-04-02'
GROUP BY c.calls_id
HAVING count(c.id) <2
```

This is what i have tried so far.. is it a proper way to use WHERE, GROUPBY, HAVING COUNT.. in CDbCriteria.. This is my search function in a model `Calls`

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = 'c.id, c.answer, c.number';
$criteria->addCondition(' c.company_id='.$this->companyId);
$criteria->addBetweenCondition(' c.answer', ''.$this->start_date.'', ''.$this->end_date.'');
$criteria->group = 'c.calls_id';
$criteria->limit < 2;
```

Any suggestions, how to achieve this in Search function of model, because i want to show the result in CGridView...

Comment: In this context, 'Less than 2' is the same as 'Equals 1', right?

Comment: Yes `$criteria->limit = 1;`

Comment: Can you clarify "how to achieve this in Search function of model"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field you group by "c.calls_id" should exist in your select statement

```
$criteria->select = 'c.id, c.answer, c.number, c.calls_id';
```

The proper statement for "having" is, for example:

```
$criteria->having = "count(c.id) < 2";
```